# Is it possible to use php inside php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm learning php and right now i have a problem i can't find an answer for.

I use

```
<?php include 'text1.php'; echo get_text($var2); ?>
```

to read this

```
<?php $var2 = "This is some text" ?>
```

to put the text on a wordpress page.

My question is:
How can i put the wordpress title right after the text `This is some text` on the wordpress page? Ie. `This is some text - Go To New York`? (Where `Go To New York` is the blogpost title)

*The php for get post title is* `<?php the_title(); ?>`

I tried this, but of course it won't work ;-)

```
<?php $var2 = "This is some text - <?php the_title(); ?>" ?>
```

Is there another way to output the wordpress title after the text?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to read php code within a PHP file?

Comment: Yes. Or if there's another way to get the blogpost name after the text

Comment: I edit the question. Hope it's more clear now :-)

Comment: Try this : `$var2 = "This is some text - ".the_title(); echo $var2;` (the_title() should return post title!) I can't provide the answer since the question put on hold.

Comment: @Jenson: the question is now off hold.

Comment: This is just a concatenation problem - search for "PHP concatenate string" for more details.

Comment: @halfer Somebody already answered..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP inside PHP, you can, but you need to remove the php tags, and in your case, append the_title() to $var2 using the [concatenation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) operator (dot).

If I understood your question right,

```
<?php include 'text1.php'; echo get_text($var2)." - ".the_title(); ?>
```